# Mixing colours in html

Tags: html

I am looking for a way to put the background colour of my website as this colour without having to use a full sized image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body style="background-color:#b0e0e6;">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container img {vertical-align: middle;}

.container .content {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(0, 0, 0); /* Fallback color */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); /* Black background with 0.5 opacity */
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <img src="images/youtube1.png" alt="Image of a phone with youtube on it" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="content">
    <h1>The History Of Youtube</h1>
    <p>Started by Jawed Karim, Steve Chen, and Chad Hurley, YouTube first launched in 2005 and has now become one of the most visited websites in the history of the internet. As employees of PayPal, the three soon realized, in 2004, that there wasn't one location where videos could be shared. Years later, Karim explained that it was the Janet Jackson Super Bowl incident as well as the tsunami in December that triggered the idea.</p>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Image link: https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.xmple.com%2Fwallpaper%2Forange-pink-gradient-linear--c2-ff69b4-d8b04d-a-30-f-14-image%2F&psig=AOvVaw0ZdrAOKDkB9tViVXEdnmhC&ust=1582726670838000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCKCgjbry7OcCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAJ

Comment: Have you looking into [`background-image: linear-gradient(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)?

Comment: Hey sorry for the question. I guess the real question was what is the name for the thing that helped mix colours on a website. I didnt know the name until i saw that it said "
Have you looking into background-image: linear-gradient(...)? – chriskirknielsen 9 mins ago
"
Now that i know the name is gradient i am able to do it. sorry for the post.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a gradient background in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428893/how-do-you-make-a-gradient-background-in-css)

Comment: You're here to learn, we're here to help, no need to apologise. I just wanted to point you in the right direction. ;) And sorry for my typo (looking -> looked), still waking up, it seems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [linear-gradient()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient)

The title of your image says

> Wallpaper orange pink gradient linear #ff69b4 #d8b04d 30°

which is all indication you need. You can write it like so in CSS

```css
.background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: linear-gradient(30deg, #d8b04d, #ff69b4);
}
```

```html
<div class="background"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you I will delete this comment as soon as you delete yours as to not seem like i ignored you xd. Thank you so much for the help <3.