# How do I make a button that turns my background into a gradient?

Tags: javascript

I can't get the original code that is supposed to make the background green when you press the button and I can't figure out how to add the gradient as the color. Please help!

here is my code:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Green <em>Gradient</em></button>

    <script>
      function myFunction()
      */I want this to be a gradient, but I cant figure out how/*
{   
document.body.style.backgroundColor= "green";
}

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you make a gradient background in css?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428893/how-do-you-make-a-gradient-background-in-css)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an example you might be able to edit to your liking.

```js
/*I want this to be a gradient, but I cant figure out how*/
function myFunction(){ 

  document.body.style.background= "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(212,211,222,1) 0%, rgba(186,215,209,1) 26%, rgba(0,255,44,1) 100%)";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Green <em>Gradient</em></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes, to simplify this. it would look like this : background: linear-gradient(to right,#FFFFFF, #278c2b);

Answer (score 0):

```js
/*I want this to be a gradient, but I cant figure out how*/
function myFunction(){ 

  document.body.style.background= "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(212,211,222,1) 0%, rgba(186,215,209,1) 26%, rgba(0,255,44,1) 100%)";
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Green <em>Gradient</em></button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! Is there  a way I can add hex color codes into it?

Comment: hi, check the comment under my answer.